# Multi-Mailbox search partially succeeded on Exchange Server 2010 SP3 Rollup 15

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am running multi-mailbox searches and 90% of the time the searches are successful, but some result in "Search partially succeeded" with the error below. Originally, I ran these searches on Exchange Server 2010 SP1, but once I encountered these errors, I consulted a [MS support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2515259/-the-items-could-not-be-copied.-error-message-when-you-run-the-get-mailboxsearch-cmdlet-in-an-exchange-server-2010-sp1-environment), which suggested upgrading the service pack and rollup. I upgraded to SP3 and Rollup 15, which I assumed would fix the errors. I am using Windows Server SBS 2011.

However, when I re-ran the search post-upgrade (and reboot), I got the same error:

> An error occurred when searching [user]. The message is 'Move/Copy
>   messages failed.'

Note that the two searches the complete partially both refer to users with admin creds -- not sure if that may be causing the problem. However, these accounts CAN be searched because all other successful searches search all email accounts, including these admin accounts.

Any idea what could be causing these errors with multi-mailbox searches?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my suspicion was correct. Once the user was remove from the 'administrator' group, the multi-mailbox search completed successfully.

Now, why it completed for 8 searches before it raised a fuss, that's a mystery and one that I do not wish to investigate.